# Speed of Card Readers Speeds of Macs

Tags: mac, performance, sd-card, system-information

**Is there a way to find the read/write speed of the SDXC card readers on Macs?**

I've been looking for it in System Information, or some chart on the web, to no avail.

---

(I'm specifically looking for rMBP Mid-2014 13", however the question is general so it is applicable to more people. However, if you happen to know the answer to this particular computer, please do share. `:)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### How fast can my Mac read or write to an SD card in the SD card slot?
>
> Mac notebooks use the USB bus to communicate with the SD card slot. They have a maximum speed of up to 480Mbit/s. Mac desktops use the PCIe bus to communicate with the SD card slot. Desktops can transfer data at a faster rate.
>
> Check the packaging that came with your SD media to determine the maximum transfer rate that your specific card uses.
>
> To determine the maximum transfer speed of your Mac, you can use the System Profiler. Go to the Apple () menu > About This Mac and then click System Report.
>
> If you use a Mac notebook:
>
> 1. Select Hardware, then select USB.
> 2. Select Internal Memory Card Reader and look for the Speed entry.
>
> If you use a Mac desktop computer:
>
> 1. Select Hardware, then select Card Reader.
> 2. Look for the Link Speed entry. Computers that use the PCIe bus express their speed as GT/s.

[About the SD and SDXC card slot on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204384)

Answer (score 0):

With the Mid 2015 Retina Macbook Pro that is currently in front of me, I'm only getting about 5.6MB/s read or write speed with the built-in slot. This is with a MicroCenter brand microSD 128GB card in a couple different adaptors as well as with an Angelbird microSD UHS-II V60 card (special card for media productions purposes). Interestingly, the MicroCenter card will work fine with a MiniDrive flush adaptor but the Angelbird doesn't ever show up when installed in the MiniDrive. Conversely, a noname micro->full side SD card adaptor works every time with the Angelbird.

This said, I seem to recall getting much better speeds with my 2013 rMBP machines with their internal SD card slots in years past.